# How to retrieve elements from another table in a SQL query?

Tags: query

I get data from a table `wp_posts` and now I need to get data from the table `wp_postmeta` that match the ID captured in `wp_posts` table .

The data that I need to grab in the table `wp_postmeta` are `product_img1` , `product_img2` , `product_img3` as shown in image below.

[image]

This is a view of my `wp_posts`:

[image]

I need to show `ID, post_title, product_img1, product_img2, product_img3`. Here's the SQL:

```
$show_info = $pdo("SELECT p.*, pm.*  
                   FROM wp_posts p  
                   JOIN wp_postmeta pm ON p.post_id = pm.meta_id 
                   WHERE p.post_type = 'wpcproduct'"
                 );
```

**Question:** Can you help me to show this data for ID 103?

Comment: What not just use a regular WordPress function, like http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: I do not have the technical knowledge to use the classes of the Codex. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a [`WP_Query()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) you can have all of them what you want in an easy way. See all the arguments available in the Codex. With the following code, we are grabbing all(`-1`) the posts from `wp_posts` table, and using the post ID we are grabbing the postmeta items.

```
<?php
$productquery = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type'=>'wpcproduct','post_status'=>'publish','posts_per_page'=>-1 ) );

if( $productquery->have_posts() ) :
   while( $productquery->have_posts() ) : $productquery->the_post();
      global $post;
      $post_id = $post->ID;

      echo '<h2>'. $post_id .' - '. get_the_title() .'</h2>';
      echo '<img src="'. get_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_img1', TRUE ) . '" alt="Product Image 1">';
      echo '<img src="'. get_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_img2', TRUE ) . '" alt="Product Image 2">';
      echo '<img src="'. get_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_img3', TRUE ) . '" alt="Product Image 3">';

   endwhile;
else :
   echo __( 'No Product\'s found', 'textdomain' );
endif;
wp_reset_postdata(); //reset the query after use
```